# Does Java RMI use server resources?

Tags: java, networking, client, rmi

I'm really new to Java RMI, and I don't quite understand what it actually does.  When a remote method is called, is the method executed on the server, or the client?  In other words does RMI utilize the servers resources or is it simply used for access to remote classes and methods which will run client side?

Comment: It uses resources on both sides, server and client.

Comment: I don't know why you think a remote method auld execute locally. What exactly would be the point of RMI?

Comment: The point would then be for simply more compact programs, and more secure remote code. A program could also be upgraded without having to actually upgrade the client, as the code on the servers side could be updated, while still the client would still call the same methods, just with updated code. @EJP

Comment: The point would be that it wouldn't be remote method invocation, whether 'more compact' or otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java RMI (Remote Method Invocation) uses client side "stubs" to connect to server side implementation and the real work is done on the Server side.